# drop down list doesnt show on mouse over

Tags: drop-down-menu, mouseover

I want to add a drop down menu in "`about us`" tab in main menu, I tried hard but its not showing,

Here is the html code for the lists,

```
<li>
       <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>  
          <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>
   </li>
```

and here is my css for the drop down menu I have created:

```
#menu ul li{float:none}
#menu ul li a{background:none !important;}
#menu ul li a:hover{background:url(../images/menu_active.gif) top repeat-x !important;display:block}
#menu ul{border:solid 1px #FC0;position: absolute;z-index: 100;background: #000;width:300px;display:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this fiddle is a working version of your code:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74b7c/)

Explanation:

You are not selecting the write `<ul>` in your css

```
    #menu ul li:hover ul{background:url(../images/menu_active.gif) top repeat-x !important;display:block;}
    #menu ul li ul{border:solid 1px #FC0;z-index:999;background: #000;width:300px;display:none;}
```

Check for the full code the JSFiddle

If you want to select a `<li>` of a `<ul>` in a `<ul>`or`<li>` Use this in your css.

```
ul li ul li {}
```

Comment: bro i hav checked wat u hav suggested .. but its showing the whole thing even if i havent hover the mouse over the "about us" tab

Comment: you have checked my fiddle? cuz that one only shows the whole thing when hovering

Comment: ya i hav checked it and its working there... but mine stil nt working.. actualy i am using a templete and modifying its menu .. it has a simple menu but i want to add dropdown list in one of its tab

Comment: which template? do you have a link or something?

Comment: here is the link of the template [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/free-templates/free-website-template-typography-jquery-slider.php)

Comment: plz tel me how to add dropdown list in this template menu

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for dropdown in pure css.

```
.sub-menu { display: none; }
.menu:hover + .sub-menu { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/greatghoul/TDA62/

Comment: by using ur suggestion its still the same... not showing the list on hover